# Phonegap control keyboard go button action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my phonegap app for iOS/Android, I have numerous input boxes spread across the app. When you click on a textbox, keyboard comes up and there is a **"GO"** button at the bottom right (iOS). What I wanted was to handle what happens when you tap on the button.

Most of the inputs were inside a form so I added an `onsubmit` event handler and everything was fine. Its when I came to text-boxes used for `data-filter` (I'm using `jQuery-mobile`) that I got stuck.

So here's one such textbox :

```
<ul id="priceListul" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Enter search term...">

     <li><div class="priceList"> 
        <label class="priceBrandLabel"> Name </label>
        <label class="pricePriceLabel"> &#8377 </label>
        <label class="priceSizeLabel"> Pack Size </label>
        <label class="priceCatLabel"> Category details </label>
     </div></li>
      <!--dont worry. more li items are added by javascript later-->
</ul>
```

The attribute `data-filter="true"` creates a filter textbox on top of the list. But I have no Idea how to catch the press of the keyboards go Button. It currently does not respond. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event to capture Go key in Keyboar(Mobile) Tested in Android Lenovo P780

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if ( (code==13) || (code==10))
                {
                  //Your code goes here
                }
            }
        });
```